# Using a KeyEvent in a method

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

If I was using a GUI and had a textField that the user would type into and then the program would type back, how would I access a KeyEvent during a method? (The keyEvent would be when the Enter key is pressed -> the text in the textfield would generate a response)

So for example: if the program asked the user (via a method) "Would you like to eat this cake?" and then the user would type in the textField "yes" or "no" and depending on the response the program would give another question or situation in another method.

pseudo code:

```
public void cakeQuestion(){
        eventList.setText(eventList.getText() + "\nWould You Like To Eat This Cake?"); //eventList is a textArea 
       //***KeyEvent takes place, perhaps saving the user's input as a String called resposne
           if(response.equals("yes"){
              eatCake //eatCake is another method with another situation
           }         
           else if(response.equals("no"){
              eatPie //eatPie is another method with another situation
           } 
           else{eventList.setText(eventList.getText() + "\nI don't understand that response");}
     }
```

Comment: @NullSaint: indeed, a nice answer. 1+

Answer (score 3):

Solution: you don't use KeyEvent. If you're waiting on the enter press in a JTextField you simply give the field an ActionListener, and this will respond on enter press.

```
myTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String response = e.getActionCommand();
        if(response.equals("yes"){
            eatCake(); //eatCake is another method with another situation
        }         
        else if(response.equals("no"){
            eatPie(); //eatPie is another method with another situation
        } else{
            eventList.setText(eventList.getText() + "\nI don't understand that response");
        }
    }
});
```

Side bits:

- If you want your GUI to only except a limited number of well defined entries, such as "yes" and "no", then don't use a JTextField but rather use something more geared toward controlled input such as JRadioButtons (added to a ButtonGroup), a JSpinner, or a JComboBox. Rather than warning the user that their input is not correct, better to not allow them to enter incorrect input in the first place.
- If you want to respond to key presses in a text component (e.g., JTextField, JTextArea...), then add a DocumentListener to the text component's Document.
- If you want to *filter* text entered int text components, e.g., check text for validity and not allow it in the field if invalid, then add a DocumentFilter to the text component's Document.

Comment: Thank you! So then to add more methods I would just add more `@Overrides` and whatever I wanted in the method?

Comment: @AtticusTrebmal: I don't understand your comment -- add more methods to what? To the ActionListener? No you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: so then how would I add another method like the actionPerformed one? Like if I want that same method with different text?

Comment: @AtticusTrebmal: Again I'm confused. If you want something similar added to another JTextField, you'd do the same thing as above. If the methods are the same, then create an ActionListener variable and add the same listener to both JTextFields.

Comment: I want to add similar methods to the same JTextField

Comment: @AtticusTrebmal: if you're listening for enter press, then this is it. Done. Finito. Period. End of story. If you want to add behaviors to this method, then expand the method. If you want something else, then *again* please clarify and please be specific.

Comment: Ohh okay I think I understand now, sorry about the confusion.